# Which antlr4-runtime?

Tags: maven, antlr4

I'm trying to add dependency **antlr4-runtime** in eclipse. It shows two instances to choose from.

1. com.tunnelvisionlabs::antlr4-runtime (324566 b)
2. org.antlr::antlr4-runtime (242694 b)

These files are of different size.

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference runtime which is described in [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference) book with JavaDocs [posted at antlr.org](http://antlr.org/api/Java/index.html) is the **org.antlr::antlr4-runtime**.

The other build is a highly experimental branch which is heavily optimized for use in Tunnel Vision Labs' IDE products. This build deviates from the documented version in many ways, so you may be on your own if you run into problems.

Comment: Noticed that the answer to [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926060/how-to-automatically-generate-lexerparser-with-antlr4-and-maven) links to [gist](https://gist.github.com/sharwell/4979017). There the groupid is **com.tunnelvisionlabs**. Is that that I need to use **com.tunnelvisionlabs**, if I want automatic code generation?

Comment: @Atul That was unintentional. I updated the gist to reference group id **org.antlr** instead.